# Retrieve object from Java Vector by using its class name

Tags: java, string, object, vector

I will start by explaining the scenario.
I have to create a Vector to hold a list of Circles.
Then I create a circle object, and add it to the Vector.
Finally I have to print the state of each circle in the list (the state isn't important to define, just it's colour and position etc).

Basically my problem is, how do I hold the circles so that I can then pass in the name of one of them and it will print the correct circle's state. It may be clearer to show you my code.

I have 3 classes, that main one called Lab83Test, the Vector one, called CircleList, and the Circle one, called Circle. (The formatting has gone weird and I can't fix it, so apologies!)

**Lab83Test:**

```
public class Lab83Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        makeNewCircle();
    }
    public static void makeNewCircle() {
        CircleList newList = new CircleList();
        Circle newCircle = new Circle();
        newList.addCircle(newCircle);
        newCircle.makeVisible();
        newList.printDetails();
    }
}
```

**CircleList:**

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class CircleList {
    private Vector circleVector;

    public CircleList() {
        circleVector = new Vector();
    }
    public void addCircle(Circle circleName) {
            circleVector.add(circleName);
            printDetails();
    }
    public void addCircleToPlace(Circle circleName, int pos) {
        circleVector.add(pos, circleName);
        printDetails();
    }
    public void removeCircleFromPos(int pos) {
        circleVector.remove(pos);
        printDetails();
    }
    public void removeAllCircles(int pos) {
        circleVector.clear();
        printDetails();
    }
    public void printDetails() {

    }
}
```

The circle class isn't too important, and it has a lot of methods for moving the circle and stuff. The main thing is that it has to return its state.

Comment: Why can't you fix the formatting? ^^

Comment: What is the "name of a Circle"? vectors only deal with access by the index of the Circle in the list

Comment: Also: what exactly do you want? I can not see what's wrong with that code except for `printDetails()` being not yet implemented.

Comment: Why don't you maintain a `Map<String, Circle>` to store mapping from name to `Circle` instance.

Comment: That's my point - I don't understand how it should be done. How would you create a Vector that holds something, and then allows you to iterate through it to call a method on all the circles in it.

Comment: Mark, by name of the circle I mean what you call it. eg Circle myCircle = new Circle();, where 'myCircle' is what I'm referring to as the name. How would the Vector store this, and how would you then go about calling a method on each Circle in the Vector from this?

Comment: @JamieWarburton.. A reference to `Circle` class is not called `circleName`. Please specify your problem clearly. And yes, posting the Circle class is important here. Have you overridden `equals` method in your Circle class?

Comment: The circle class is a constructor, defining default variables of diameter and x and y, and a method that returns these that `printDetails()` will be calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to iterate over all `Circel` in your list and print their name, you can do it this way:

```
public void printDetails() {
  for (Circle c: circleVector) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s: center=(%.1f/%.1f) radius=%.1f", c.getName(), c.getCenterX(), c.getCenterY(), c.getRadius()));
  }
}
```

I don't know how your `Circle` class looks so I just assumed some method names.

If you want to find a specific circle by name:

```
for (Circle c: circleVector) {
  if (c.getName().equals(nameToFind)) return c;
}
```

Or you could use a `Map<String, Circle>` instead of your vector and just do `return circleMap.get(name);`. Your `addCircle()` would then look like this:

```
public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
  circleMap.add(circle.getName(), circle);
  printDetails();
}
```

**Edit1:** regarding your comment: Your vector does not have a defined type. Change this:

```
...
public class CircleList {
  private Vector<Circle> circleVector;

  public CircleList() {
    circleVector = new Vector<Circle>();
  }
  ...
```

Comment: That's what I tried before, though I get the error 
`found   : java.lang.Object
required: Circle`
I've not quite grasped this yet so I'm not sure what it's asking for

Comment: Because your Vector does not specify it's type. Try `Vector<Circle>` instead. -> see **Edit1**

Comment: @brimborium.. Of course the content in the bracket is a terrible idea. So, you can remove it from valuable option.

Comment: @RohitJain Agreed, that's why I put it into brackets. But you're right, removed it... ;)

Comment: Thank you so much brimborium, that works perfectly. My lecturer very good at teaching one thing, and then setting work based on something completely different, so I'm stabbing in the dark at a lot of things and I just could not work this one out. Thanks very much!